# Point Phusion passenger to home directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, passenger

I'm deploying a Rails application on inmotion hosting at `coolmappdb.com` - and when I get there it says

```
Could not spawn process for application /home/username/public_html/coolmappdb.com: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
<p>If that didn't work, then maybe the problem is that your gems are installed to <code>/home/username/.rvm/gems</code>, while at the same time you set <code>PassengerRuby</code> (Apache) or <code>passenger_ruby</code> (Nginx) to <code>/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/wrappers/ruby</code>. Because of the latter, RVM does not load gems from the home directory.</p>
```

The error message is clear. It is saying that my Phusion Passenger is pointed at the wrong location. How can I make it work at the right location?

**UPDATES:**

```
<VirtualHost 170.239.250.29:80>
  ServerName coolmappdb.com
  ServerAlias www.coolmappdb.com
  DocumentRoot /home/coolma7/public_html
  PassengerRuby /home/coolma7/.rvm/gems
  ServerAdmin webmaster@coolmappdb.com
  UseCanonicalName Off
  CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/coolmappdb.com combined
  <IfModule log_config_module>
    <IfModule logio_module>
      CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/coolmappdb.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the directories? I had a similar problem once because I had created a user to run this my ruby apps but the gems were installed in a directory whose permissions were not correctly set for this user to read.

Comment: yes code is in public folders

Comment: Are you using Apache or Nginx ?

Comment: Then set, inside your VirtualServer, `PassengerRuby` to `/home/[username]/.rvm/gems`, with [username] being your user name.

Comment: This is clearly not your Apache configuration, but an example you took somewhere. Please post your configuration, because the problem may be in the  differences and we'll never see it.

Answer (score 1):

I visited the application at http://coolmappdb.com/ and there you find the reason of your problem.

As I said in my first comment to your question, you have a problem with permissions, as it says in you Phusion error page:

```
*** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /home/coolma7/.rvm/gems: Permission denied (13)
```

It happens that you have

```
Ruby interpreter command = /home/coolma7/.rvm/gems
```

and in the "Environment variables" section you may find the following

```
MY_RUBY_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1
```

It happens that your Ruby interpreter can't run anything in a system folder like /usr/local.

To fix this you have to set, inside your Apache's VirtualServer the following

```
PassengerRuby "/home/coolma7/.rvm/gems"
```

This will make your Ruby interpreter search for the gems in the correct place, where you have all permissions needed.

Make sure your Apache is running as a user with permissions to execute inside `/home/coolma7`, setting `User` and `Group` correctly at Apache's configuration file.

Finally, the fact that you have gems at `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1` means the you are using a system Ruby. This is not recommended. Try to stick to RVM when installing Ruby versions and you'll have less problems. See [this](http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com/2015/10/dont-give-up-rvm.html). And maybe [this post](http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com/2015/12/phusion-passenger-x-rails-composer.html) may help you too.

Comment: in apache i already have `PassengerRuby "/home/coolma7/.rvm/gems"` line in virtual host . check my updated question please